# Replacing a comma (,) with a dot (.)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SSMS, beginner in SQL
I want to replace varchar values which contains commas, to dots to parse through on other software which reads dots as floating values
But from what I gathered, the Replace only works in a select and does not do it permanently.
I want to see that *22 rows affected* where commas was replaced

Example of data

```
HoursSpent
8,3
1,55
2,6
7,2
```

Example of end result

```
HoursSpent
8.3
1.55
2.6
7.2
```

Comment: If you want to change the value in the table permanently use `UPDATE` command

Comment: The issue is with your database. Why do you store numbers as strings? Store them as numbers and you are fine.

Comment: Once you have done the update you should then change the column datatype to something like `numeric(6,2)` and not store numbers as strings

Comment: Thank you the Query worked so good thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use UPDATE to make changes:

```
UPDATE table SET HoursSpent=REPLACE(HoursSpent,',','.');
```

Comment: You saved me tons of time thanks